# Always receiving event.data as null,push event service worker

Tags: firebase, curl, push-notification, postman, service-worker

I came across the same question, but can't solved my problem yet.
I am getting the success response and the notification bar, but data in event is null so notification bar shows static data that I gave.

[image]

this is the body am passing.

[image]

this is header part. And the result is,

[image]

then a push notification bar shown successfully. But data is null, that is I console the event

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(e) {

console.log(e);



var body;
if (e.data) {
    body = e.data.json();
  } else {
    body = 'Push message no payload';
  }
```

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: could you please try send body in this format                                                
{
    "data":{
        /*your data object like*/
         "name":"abcdefg",
         "id":1234
       },
      "registration_ids":"your device id array"
    }